# Discord.js "channel" not defined error message

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I recently became interested in making a discord bot using Javascript and node.js. I am trying to make a command that spins a virtual "lottery", and sends a message telling the user whether they have received anything. (Here is my code:)

`

```
function lotteryCommand(arguments, receivedMessage){


/*note: receivedMessage is defined as the command (for my bot, it's e!spin) 
  and arguments is the part following the command (for this particular bit of code, 
  it's merits, so the user sends "e!spin merits")*/

    if (arguments == "merits"){
        setTimeout(randomlottery1, 1000);
    }
    else{receivedMessage.channel.send("Message here")}
    }
```

here is the other function. **This is where it stops working**

```
  function randomlottery1(arguments, receivedMessage){
    let respond;
    let responses = [
        //some random phrases here
    ]
    respond = responses[Math.floor(Math.random() * responses.length)]
    receivedMessage.channel.send(respond)
}
```

For some reason I cannot understand, it does not recognize the `channel` in `receivedMessage.channel.send` the *second* time, in the `randomlottery1` function, but it recognized the command earlier in the code. Is there anything I am doing wrong here? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is you are not passing in any parameters to your function, you can easily fix it by doing this:

```js
function lotteryCommand(arguments, receivedMessage){


/*note: receivedMessage is defined as the command (for my bot, it's e!spin) 
  and arguments is the part following the command (for this particular bit of code, 
  it's merits, so the user sends "e!spin merits")*/

    if (arguments == "merits"){
            // dont forget to pass in the required parameters while executing your function (parameter1, parameter2)
            setTimeout(randomlottery1(arguments, receivedMessage), 1000);
    }
    else{receivedMessage.channel.send("Message here")}
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually, it stopped working because I specified parameters I didn't need. Thank you anyway!